# Coffee package puts coffee stain behind pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

The `coffee` package is great fun, however on documents with figures the coffee is placed behind the figures.  It seems improper to do this on a printed version.  How do I get my coffee on top of the figures?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage[onEveryPage]{coffee}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subbottom[A \label{fig:examplea}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=20cm]{example-image-a}}
    \hspace{0.1\columnwidth}
    \subbottom[B\label{fig:exampleb}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=10cm]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Example A and B}
    \label{fig:examples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which might produce this (the coffee spot is random):
[image]

Comment: The “stains” are in the background layer.

Comment: @egreg but is it possible to get them on the front layer?

Comment: I don't doubt that it is possible. But as the coffee sty here http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349 doesn't know an "onEveryPage" option and as there is no coffee sty on CTAN, it is quite unclear which commands your version of the sty  uses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's an upgrade to the http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349 package from the github of Echsecutor: https://github.com/Echsecutor/coffee It's the coffe5 package (i renamed it when i put it in my folder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load the eso-pic yourself and then place the coffee stain:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage{coffee}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\cofeSplash{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subbottom[A \label{fig:examplea}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=20cm]{example-image-a}}
    \hspace{0.1\columnwidth}
    \subbottom[B\label{fig:exampleb}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=10cm]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Example A and B}
    \label{fig:examples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If that's meant to be coffee, I'm sticking to tea ....

Comment: Will this solution put a random splash on every page? (the coffee5 class readjusts the size, location and rotation of all of the four coffee splashes n the original coffee class, and put's one on each page)

Comment: Why don't you simply try it out?

Comment: I'm sorry for being so slow at accepting your answer,  I was writing my bachelors thesis and apparently I asked this question around 18 hours before deadline, so I had thrown it off my mind.