# A decorations packages of LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, pstricks, decorations

I'm looking for decorations packages of LaTeX. So far, what I know is the:

1. [Adforn](https://ctan.org/pkg/adforn?lang=en)
2. [Pgfornament](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament?lang=en)
3. [Psvectorian](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian?lang=en) (I don't see differences between this and `pgfornament`...)

So, can you tell me please about more packages like those? (It's OK if they're like `pgfornament` and they need other packages for using them).

Comment: Are coffee stains a decoration? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374998

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you have specific requirements that are not fulfilled with the packages that you list? Or are you just curious which packages are available? Some more examples can be found on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/where-can-i-find-examples-of-decorated-borders-margins.

Comment: @Marijn - I'm just curious... :) Thank you for your links (although they contained the packages I mention).

Comment: @Thérèse, I meant to something else - but thank you for your link... :-)