# Cover table with stains

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am trying to recreate the following table

[image]

So far I have managed to create the following

[image]

What is missing is the blobs / stains covering parts of the table. I have no idea how to insert them, maybe tikz?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c l r l r l r l r}
\midrule
  \textbf{År} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Avdrag}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Renter}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Terminbeløp}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Restlån}} \\ 
\midrule
  2018 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{182554} \\
  2019 & kr & \num{17969} & kr & \num{5477} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{164585}  \\
  2020 & kr & \num{18508} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{146076}  \\
  2921 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{127012}  \\
  2022 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{107377}  \\
  2023 & kr &             & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{}  \\
  2024 & kr & \num{20953} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{}  \\
  2025 & kr & \num{21}    & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{44864}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please give us the code of the stains?

Comment: I dont have them? This is part of the problem.

Comment: So what is the question then? How to draw the stain or how to add them to the table (please do not ask two seperate questions in one question)

Comment: print  on A4 paper then place a coffee cup on the paper and shake the table.

Comment: You can use coffee stains provided by `coffee` package and put on top with this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375002/1952

Answer (score 5):

It seems the coffee package (olsak-misc) has been updated since the previous questions.  They are now implemented as literal PDF inserts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{fun-coffee}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rlap{\hspace*{-1.5in}\raisebox{-1in}[0pt][0pt]{\scalebox{0.8}{\coffeeA}}}% adjust position
\indent\lipsum[1-4]
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\path (current page.center)
  node[opacity=0.2,  inner sep=0pt] {\coffeeA};
  \draw[blue] (current page.center) ++(6.5,-4.4) circle[radius=4];}% trial and error

\newpage
\coffeeB
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\coffeeC
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\coffeeD
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

---

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\input{fun-coffee}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[]
\coffeeA
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c l r l r l r l r}
\midrule
  \textbf{År} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Avdrag}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Renter}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Terminbeløp}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Restlån}} \\ 
\midrule
  2018 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{182554} \\
  2019 & kr & \num{17969} & kr & \num{5477} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{164585}  \\
  2020 & kr & \num{18508} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{146076}  \\
  2921 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{127012}  \\
  2022 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{107377}  \\
  2023 & kr &             & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{}  \\
  2024 & kr & \num{20953} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{}  \\
  2025 & kr & \num{21}    & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{44864}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Darn Table keeps wobbling with your current 2nd mwe values could be `\coffeeB 
\raisebox{1in}\coffeeC
\raisebox{2in}\coffeeA`

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement a stain for yourself with some Ti*k*Z `\path` commands and some path operations. Then you can use `tikzmark` package. Here the "stain" is a filled circle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\tikzmark{origin}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c l r l r l r l r}
\midrule
  \textbf{År} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Avdrag}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Renter}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Terminbeløp}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Restlån}} \\ 
\midrule
  2018 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{182554} \\
  2019 & kr & \num{17969} & kr & \num{5477} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{164585}  \\
  2020 & kr & \num{18508} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{146076}  \\
  2921 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{127012}  \\
  2022 & kr & \num{17446} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{107377}  \\
  2023 & kr &             & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{}  \\
  2024 & kr & \num{20953} & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{}  \\
  2025 & kr & \num{21}    & kr & \num{6000} & kr & \num{23446} & kr & \num{44864}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\filldraw[fill=yellow] (pic cs:origin)++(3,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Btw there is (probably) a typo: 2021 not 2921 I think.