# Remove double empty pages before book chapters

Tags: books, emptypage, cleardoublepage

I was wondering how to remove the double empty pages before Chapter 1 and the Bibliography in the following book example. I tried `\cleardoublepage` and `\usepackage{emptypage}` with no success. I believe it is due to setting the interline spacing with `\onehalfspacing` using `\usepackage{setspace}`, but I need this function. The argument `openany` for `\documentlass` is not desired.

Any suggestions to make the document quality more elegant would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book Title}

\author{Author}
\date{}

\newcommand\institute{
    Department \par \medskip
    University \par
    City, State}
    

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
    \makeatletter
    \centering
    {\LARGE\bfseries\baselineskip1.25em\@title\par} \par
    \vfill
    {\large\bfseries\@author} \par
    \@date
    \makeatother
    \vfill
    \pgfornament[width=.35\linewidth]{84} \bigskip \par
    \institute
\end{titlepage}

% Empty page
\phantom{}
\pagebreak

% Dedication
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begingroup
\centering
    \lipsum[1-1]
\endgroup
\vspace*{\fill}

\chapter{Preface}  
\lipsum[2-3]

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4-6]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title of Chapter 1}
\lipsum[5-25]
\cite{Akhiezer62}

\chapter{Title of Chapter 2}
\lipsum[30-45]

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
    \bibitem[Akhiezer(1962)]{Akhiezer62}
    N.~I. Akhiezer.
    \newblock \emph{The Calculus of Variations}.
    \newblock Blaisdell Publishing Company, New York, London, 1962.
\end{thebibliography}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: removing `\topskip0pt`  helps (you have no chance of a good layout when it is zero)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the suggestion. It helps, but I want to have the Dedication vertically centered with respect to the page.

Comment: you applied  it on every page making it  impossible to set the first line of text in a consistent way

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Would you please let me know how to apply it to the Dedication page only?

Comment: move the `\begingroup` up a couple of lines, but I am suspicious about that setting and whether you want it at all

Comment: It depends on what you consider elegant.  Setspace is used to make documents look like they were written on a typewriter, in which cas you might also consider a non-propotional font.  There is also a package for adding coffee stains.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: What do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492241/cover-table-with-stains/492297?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C30.3204#492297 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidCarlisle comment above, I believe removing `\topskip0pt` solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).